# Why we declare some variables in PHP as like "$_variablename"...?

Tags: php, oop, variables

Why we declare some variables in PHP as like `$_variablename`?

Does `_` define something?

Please help me to clear this up, thanks.

Comment: There is no *inherent* meaning to the underscore. It's individual developer's naming preference.

Comment: Leading underscores are generally used for private properties and methods. It was old practice in PHP when private methods was not implemented in PHP

Comment: No _ does not defines variable or function private it's a naming convention just to remind variable or function is private

Comment: This is not a duplicate... The linked post is talking about class methods and this one is for variables. This post confirm that it's the same convention for variables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a naming convention.

From the [pear manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php) on naming conventions:

> Private class members are preceded by a single underscore. For example:

```
$_status
```

Answer (score 6):

The underscore does not mean that the variable is private. It is not necessary to use the underscore. It’s simply a naming convention that reminds the developer that the variable/property/method is either private or protected

For Example

```
// This variable is not available outside of the class  
private $_someVariable;  

class MyClass {  
   // This method is only available from within this class, or  
   // any others that inherit from it.   
   protected function __myFunction() {}  
}
```

In the code above, the underscore is not what makes the variable or method private; the private/protected keyword does that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory to use '_' or '__' in your code but it helps you to understand the variable/function access type by just seeing the name.

In some PHP frameworks you may see:

```
_ for protected variable/function

__ for private variable/function
```

Answer (score -4):

this is mainly used to declare global variable and to in function.. generally it is not compulsory to use '_' this

http://php.net/ check this